# Questions are raised or raise or rise?

Tags: transitivity

> 1. They raised important questions concerning this problem.
> 2. Important questions are raised concerning this problem.
> 3. Important questions raise concerning this problem.

I know that 1 and 2 are correct. Is 3 correct too equally? I guess my question relates to transitivity of the verb ‘to raise’ but I don’t know how to make sure about the correctness of 3. Is it a good idea to use ‘rise’ instead of ‘raise’ in 3?

Answer (score 3):

"Raise" is a transitive verb and requires a direct object, but that's not the only issue with sentence #3. The subject, "important questions", isn't actually performing the action of raising (or rising).

The appropriate word here would be the intransitive verb "arise", meaning "to begin to occur or to exist : to come into being or to attention" ([Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arise)).

*Important questions arise concerning this problem.*

Comment: M-W does say that 'raise' _is_ used intransitively, but adds a 'dialect' caveat. However, it doesn't mention with which sense/s of 'rise', and I'm sure the usage is generally best avoided.